# Problem using the API Mercure with Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, mercure

Here is the ***error message*** :
Argument 1 passed to App\Controller\PublisherController::index() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Mercure\Publisher, instance of Symfony\Component\Mercure\Debug\TraceablePublisher given, called in /home/gw01/Etna/PLI/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php on line 145 (500 Internal Server Error)

**PublisherController :**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Mercure\Publisher;
use Symfony\Component\Mercure\Update;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

/**
 * Class PublisherController
 * @package App\Controller
 */
class PublisherController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/publish/{topic}", name="publisher", methods={"POST"})
     */
    public function index(Publisher $publisher, $topic, Request $request)
    {
        $publisher(new Update($topic, $request->getContent()));
        return new Response('success');
    }
}
```

**How can i **fix** this** ?

Comment: No actual experience with mercure, but I'd say changing the typehint to `PublisherInterface` should do the trick.